# pygame error: DLL load failed (Win32)

Tags: python, pygame

I am running Windows 7 64-bit, and I have Python 2.6.7 32-bit installed, as well as pygame 1.9.1 for win-32. However, when I import the pygame module, I get the following error:

```
import pygame

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the 64 bit versions of pygame, as well as a 64bit build of python.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: Is there any other solution? I used to have 64-bit Python, but it seems like a huge hassle to get the 64-bit version of all the other modules that I have. Are they all easily available?

Comment: Installing the 32-bit version of pygame from your link worked. Thanks!